# Sync failed - Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0

Tags: android, google-play-services

I tried to run a project which was generated on someone else's PC, but sync fails and I get this error when cleaning the project:

```
  Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services/9.4.0/play-services-9.4.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services/9.4.0/play-services-9.4.0.jar
         file:/C:/Users/win7/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/9.4.0/play-services-9.4.0.pom
         file:/C:/Users/win7/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/9.4.0/play-services-9.4.0.jar
         file:/C:/Users/win7/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/9.4.0/play-services-9.4.0.pom
         file:/C:/Users/win7/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/9.4.0/play-services-9.4.0.jar
     Required by:
         Map:app:unspecified
```

Comment: You probably don't even need all the Play Services in your app anyways. You should split them apart. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split

Answer (score 0):

> was generated on someone other's PC on mine

They probably have the SDK repositories installed and you do not.

Seems like you are missing the Google Play Services Repository.

[image: g play services]

Comment: Are you sure your SDK is set to `C:/Users/win7/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1` in the "SDK PATH" of that window?